# Insert data into csv file based on data thats contained elsewhere in the file using batch file

Tags: batch-file, csv

Ok, I have another CSV related question. I will try to explain this as best as I can. Using a batch file, I need to insert a value into a column on the csv based on a value in the first column of the CSV. For instance, if column A contains the value "BCD", then insert "Value1" onto the corresponding lines in column B. If column A contains the value "HIJ", then inset "Value2" onto the corresponding lines in column B. See below example of what I require:

```
Input:

ABCDE OTHERDATA OTHERDATA
ABCDE OTHERDATA OTHERDATA
ABCDE OTHERDATA OTHERDATA
FGHIJ OTHERDATA OTHERDATA
FGHIJ OTHERDATA OTHERDATA
FGHIJ OTHERDATA OTHERDATA

Output:

ABCDE Value1 OTHERDATA OTHERDATA
ABCDE Value1 OTHERDATA OTHERDATA
ABCDE Value1 OTHERDATA OTHERDATA
FGHIJ Value2 OTHERDATA OTHERDATA
FGHIJ Value2 OTHERDATA OTHERDATA
FGHIJ Value2 OTHERDATA OTHERDATA
```

I hope I have explained this well enough!

Comment: How many values are you working with?

Comment: What shoud be done if no match in data? What should be done if both strings match? What character is separating the fields? How many fields? What is the record length? How many records? What is the content of the records? Any "problematic" character in the records? Different answer to any of this questions can change the answer.

Comment: I'll be working with over a hundred values. There will always be a match. Any that match should have the data corresponding on that row, multiple values will match. Comma separated fields. 3 fields initially, to be increased to 4 with the additional data. The field contains a "-", not sure if this would cause issues. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
(
FOR /f "tokens=1*" %%a IN (q22150040.txt) DO (
 SET "insert="
 FOR /f "tokens=1*" %%h IN (insert.txt) DO (
  ECHO %%a|FINDSTR "%%h" >nul
  IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 SET "insert=Y"&ECHO(%%a %%i %%b
  )
 IF NOT DEFINED insert (ECHO(%%a %%b)
 )
)
)>newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q22150040.txt` containing your data for my testing.

`Insert.txt` contains

```
BCD Value1
HIJ Value2
```

Comment: Tried this but it didn't output any file, any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define the replacement set
set n=0
for %%a in ("BCD=Value1"
            "HIJ=Value2") do (
   set /A n+=1
   set "rep[!n!]=%%~a"
)

(for /F "tokens=1*" %%a in (input.txt) do (
   set "col1=%%a"
   set insert=NotFound
   for /L %%i in (1,1,%n%) do for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%x in ("!rep[%%i]!") do (
      if "!col1:%%x=!" neq "%%a" set insert=%%y
   )
   echo %%a !insert! %%b
)) > output.txt
```

**EDIT**: *Output example added*

```
C:\> type input.txt
ABCDE OTHERDATA OTHERDATA
ABCDE OTHERDATA OTHERDATA
ABCDE OTHERDATA OTHERDATA
FGHIJ OTHERDATA OTHERDATA
FGHIJ OTHERDATA OTHERDATA
FGHIJ OTHERDATA OTHERDATA

C:\> test

C:\> type Output.txt
ABCDE Value1 OTHERDATA OTHERDATA
ABCDE Value1 OTHERDATA OTHERDATA
ABCDE Value1 OTHERDATA OTHERDATA
FGHIJ Value2 OTHERDATA OTHERDATA
FGHIJ Value2 OTHERDATA OTHERDATA
FGHIJ Value2 OTHERDATA OTHERDATA
```

Comment: This is the closest one so far, however it doesn't insert "Value1" into the second column on its own, it merges it with the data that's already in there. How would I make it so that it shifts the data along by one column and populates the second column alone? Many thanks!

Comment: @user3361017: I am afraid I don't understand your concern. See the edit in my answer above...

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. Basically it inserts the Value1 on the end of the OTHERDATA rather than in a new column. Also what I didn't mention which may affect it is that there are spaces in some of the data in the other columns. In these cases it appears to put the Value1 where the space is, for example ABCDE, OTHER Value1 DATA, OTHER DATA. I hope this makes sense!

Comment: Excuse me, I am confused now. You showed us an example data and the desired output. My program take _your_ data and produce _exactly_ the requested output, but now you said that the program is wrong because the real data is different! `;-<` Why you just didn't showed us the _real_ data in first place?

Answer (score 0):

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

```
type "file.csv"|repl "(.*BCD.*?) " "$1 Value1 "|repl "(.*HIJ.*?) " "$1 Value2 " >"newfile.csv"
```